# Anaconda Navigator crashing after launch, Windows 10

Tags: anaconda, python-3.5

Anaconda Navigator is crashing after lauching Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda Navigator and installing pandas-datareader “conda install -c conda-forge pandas-datareader”.
What is causing this?

Comment: remove pandas-datareader (conda remove pandas-datareader) didn't solve the problem. Upgrade Anaconda Navigator (conda update anaconda-navigator) solved the crashing problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might using an old version of navigator. Please update to the latest version.

```
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda install navigator-updater
```